# .htaccess 301 redirect http://olddomain.com/post/post-title to http://newdomain.com/story/post-title

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect http://olddomain.com/post/post-title to http://newdomain.com/story/post-title

My .htaccess rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/story/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it isn't working for some reason. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `RewriteBase` in your code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/story/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `mod_rewrite` is enabled for your site? Do you have other redirects working correctly?